# Native stack is only available if React Native Screens is enabled

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, storybook, storyshots, react-native-screens

When I try to run tests for storyshots with native screens enabled for react-navigation I get this:

Native stack is only available if React Native Screens is enabled.

```
  15 | const getRenderedTree = (story: any) => {
  16 |   const storyElement = story.render()
> 17 |   const tree = renderer.create(storyElement)
     |                                         ^
  18 | 
  19 |   return tree
  20 | }
```